# Does Safe Elements prevent Steam Knight damage?

Tags: pathfinder-2e, kineticist

[Safe Elements](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=4190): you can designate a number of creatures up to your Constitution modifier ... Choose whether they are immune to the benefits of your kinetic aura or immune to its damage and drawbacks.

If I designate my allies to be immune to the aura drawbacks, would it make them immune to [Steam Knight](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=4309) damage when I Leap over them or emit steam? Steam Knight is a stance so it could be argued that the damage isn't direct drawback of the aura but then again Steam Knight is shaping the aura and the steam deals damage to creatures inside the aura so it can also be argued that Safe Elements should work.

What would be your interpretation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Safe Elements** protects your allies from the damaging effects of **Steam Knight**

**Steam Knight** says

> **You shape your kinetic aura into swirling armor of steam** that scalds your enemies and propels you on super-heated jet streams. A creature can take damage from Steam Knight only once per round

The aura **is** the Steam that deals damage.

Furthermore, the actual text of **Safe Elements** is

> When you Channel Elements or **use a stance impulse** that affects your kinetic aura, you can designate a number of creatures up to your Constitution modifier (minimum 1 creature)

The feature is clearly intended to work with Stance Impulses, and **Steam Knight** is a stance impulse.